# Anydesk is completly locking my Ubuntu 14.04 OS?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, syslog, lock

I was using anydesk 2.9.5 version but it is freezing my computer. Also upgrade to latest version of anydesk 4.0 free personel program but it is locking all my system and my 14.04 OS is completely freezing. I have to hard reset to continue.

This is the uname -a result:

> Linux OMEN 4.4.0-134-generic #160~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 17 11:07:07 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any opinion?

Thanks.

Comment: Also tested with team viewer 13 and it is also freezing my computer. What is the relation between two remote connection program and operating system?

Comment: Upgraded all updates (sudo update & upgrade) but problem continues...

Comment: Does `/var/log/messages` say anything interesting around the time where the systems froze ?

Comment: Thanks Soren. There was nvidia driver problem line on /var/log/syslog. I also post answer the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was related to nvidia drivers update on my computer.

I uninstalled all nvidia drivers below command and problem gone away..

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```