# AnyDesk stuck on the client computer Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, freeze

I am running the newest version of Anydesk 4.1 for Ubuntu 18.04 on both client and host sides. Very often, my Anydesk stucks (freeze) on the client computer. For example, when I type something outside on my host Anydesk, the words come on the client side and not on the host sides. Another time, I moved my mouse on the host sides, but it moves on the client sides. The mouse and keyboard cannot go back to the host sides. The only way to resolve this is to press the power button on the host sides. Are there any solutions to this?

Similar questions, but do not work:
[Anydesk is completly locking my Ubuntu 14.04 OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076589/anydesk-is-completly-locking-my-ubuntu-14-04-os)
I am also not sure what he means by "locking", so I created this question.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I can confirm this happen on Ubuntu 18.04 and when you try to switch tabs on your ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Is your network connection stable? A dodgy internet connection seems to manifest from the client side as the remote session freezing up (though I know from people at the location that the remote host is responsive). Sometimes this persists after the network is re-established. You can reset this with `sudo service anydesk restart` and start a new session from the client.

There is also some condition where the client's mouse input will "lock out" the users at the remote end. It seems there is an interlock that prevents both parties from inputting at the same time, and occasionally it sticks.

Comment: It happens specifically when you switch tabs, so it may not be related to the internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer, but it is better than the hard restart.

When your anydesk stuck on the remote computer, just alt + tab until the anydesk screen pop up on the remote computer, then press alt + f4 so the anydesk on the remote computer close. After the anydesk connection is close, the client computer will be unstuck. 
You can connect to anydesk again as usual.

Comment: if its frozen, alt+tab will not do anything.

Comment: IIRC, it is only frozen on the client computer, but not the remote computer. So, you can still alt+tab on the remote computer and close the anydesk connection from the remote computer. That way, the anydesk connection on the client computer will be cut as well and the client computer will be unstuck. A reminder that you are still connecting to the remote computer and can do anything on it when it is stuck on the client computer.